# Dynamically set choices in django?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, orm

How can I allow a user to dynamically set the status of a record?

I don't want to set the statuses in place and the model needs to be able to work across many models, such as "CampaignStatus", etc.

```
class Status(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return '%s' % (self.title)

def choices(self):
    queryset = list(Status.objects.filter(task=self))
    return queryset

class Task(models.Model):
    status = models.IntegerField(choices=choices)

class TaskStatus(Status):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

This gives me the error: `'choices' must be an iterable (e.g., a list or tuple).`

How can I filter through the Status models to only have choices that are related to the TaskStatus?

**As a quick example, something like this but that would allow for me to filter only related objects:**

```
class Status(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True)
    
class Task(models.Model):
    status = models.ForeignKey(Status, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='currentstatus')

class TaskStatus(Status):
    task = models.ForeignKey(Task, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

Comment: What does `Status.objects.filter(task=self)` even mean?? And what is the problem with the second approach? Also you say _"Status models to only have choices that are related to the TaskStatus"_ which doesn't make much sense how does `TaskStatus` even come into the picture except that it is related to `Task`? Your question lacks clarity on what you want to do.

Comment: I want to be able to dynamically set a status instead of hardcoding them.  So when a task is made, I can apply custom statuses to it

Comment: I think the problem might be `models.IntegerField(choices=choices)` choices is a function and choices param expects a iterator. You might need to call it in order to get iterator returned by choices function.